# How to make this shape in css or through SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am wondering if below black shape can be made through css, or we need to use SVG for it, please provide css if possible.

[image]

In above image, the shape of black div is quite tricky to be done through css, please suggest.

Comment: Why do you want it to be part of CSS/SVG and not a part of image?

Comment: Do you mean just the black shape behind “mobile number”?

Comment: If you’re still interested, you can check out the following link: http://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/

Comment: yes only black shape

Comment: because for my different projects, color would be different for that shape @Slava

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It can be done by svg, but going not so far, we can do that by css3 also.

```css
div {
  margin: 60px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
    background-color: #555;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
   transform: rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #555;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Phone Number</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [rough sketch](http://codepen.io/demonarch/pen/NjwJZK) .
You can do it with help of :before and :after pseudo elements. then try to mess with border as suggested [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

```
.bigbox:before{
  content:'';
  color:red;
  top:90px;
  left:8px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 210px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  position:absolute;
}
```